# Is it possible that writing too quickly to an sd card can result in quicker failure?

Tags: sd, android, data-storage

I found [this post](https://old.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/bh27j9/corrupted_sd_card_works_fine_on_my_linux_laptop/) suggesting that writing too quickly to an sd card will shorten its lifespan. The context is an sd card that will be used as external storage on android, written to with rsync. The poster suggests this can result in too many missed bits, resulting in the android phone flagging the card as corrupted.

Additionally they speculate that this is due to the inability of the master boot record on sd card storage to be rewritten. Does this make sense?

Comment: I didn't see anything in your referenced post that mentioned "shortening the lifespan".

Comment: Not explicitly but if it fails quicker would that not be a shorter lifespan?

Comment: No.  Lifespan for flash devices is almost exclusively determined by the number of write cycles, to a given location.  Writing bad data that the memory receives is not a device failure.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write too quickly to an SD card. The card allows the host to write as quickly as it can. If the card has a bug and says to host it is ready before it really is then it will fail. And of course the bus clock must be below or equal to what the card can handle, or it won't work. Bus transactions are generally protected by CRC so simple errors can be detected and retried.

So it does not matter what program or how fast you copy data to SD card. The card will wear out by the same amount.

Answer (score 1):

A higher clock speed code result in more missed bits if the clock speed is changing and if there is noise from crosstalk or other sources. A proper PCB layout would mitigate most noise so it really is dependent on the design of the SD card bus.

If you were talking about the internal workings of the controller and the memory then there's no way to comment on this because this would be highly dependent on how the SD card is designed internally